# Error on scroll texture shader based on Alan Zucconi's book

Tags: unity-game-engine, fragment-shader

Using unity 5.5 and Alan Zucconi's book I'm getting " incorrect number of arguments to numeric-type constructor"

shader source added as reccommended:

```
    Shader "book/scroller"
    {
    Properties
    {
    _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    _ScrollXSpeed ("x scroll speed", Range(0,10)) = 2
    _ScrollYSpeed("Y scroll speed", Range(0,10)) = 2
}
SubShader
{
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    LOD 100

    Pass
    {
        CGPROGRAM
        #pragma vertex vert
        #pragma fragment frag


        #include "UnityCG.cginc"

        struct appdata
        {
            float4 vertex : POSITION;
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
        };

        struct v2f
        {
            float2 uv : TEXCOORD0;
            UNITY_FOG_COORDS(1)
            float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
        };

        sampler2D _MainTex;
        float4 _MainTex_ST;
        fixed _ScrollXSpeed;
        fixed _ScrollYSpeed;

        v2f vert (appdata v)
        {
            v2f o;
            o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
            o.uv = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.uv, _MainTex);
            UNITY_TRANSFER_FOG(o,o.vertex);
            return o;
        }

        fixed4 frag (v2f i) : SV_Target
        {

            fixed2 scrolledUV = i.uv;
            fixed2 xScrolledValue = _ScrollXSpeed * _Time;
            fixed2 yScrolledValue = _ScrollYSpeed * _Time;
            scrolledUV += fixed2 (xScrolledValue, yScrolledValue);
            fixed4 col = tex2D(_MainTex, scrolledUV);
            return col;
        }
        ENDCG
    }
}
```

}

Error shows at following line:

```
scrolledUV += fixed2 (xSCrolledValue, ySCrolledValue);
```

What is wrong with it?

Comment: PLease post some code and context. Its not like everybody will go and buy the same book to find out what are you talking about. Obviously you are trying to call method with wrong number of parameters. Check your method then

Comment: @Łukasz Motyczka added source, thanks for the recommendation

Comment: probably xScrolledValue and yScrolledValue should be fixed/float, not fixed2

Comment: @mgear That was it! Would you like to add it as answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for the error:
You are creating fixed2-variable and giving it two fixed2 values as parameters, should be floats instead.

Here is a **fixed** version:

```
fixed xScrolledValue = _ScrollXSpeed * _Time;
fixed yScrolledValue = _ScrollYSpeed * _Time;
scrolledUV += fixed2 (xScrolledValue, yScrolledValue);
```